# Update record via Flow does not create a Feed Item

Tags: visual-workflow, feeditem

I have a Record Triggered flow on Account, of the type Fast Field Updates.

This flow, amongst other things, updates the Type field. I have configured feed tracking for that field. I observe that the flow, when triggered, changes the Type, but in the feed of the account I do not see a post.

If I change Type manually, I see a post.

Is this a feature of flows, that they do not post Feed Items when they do field updates? Is this some setting I can change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had posted the update (that triggered the flow) via Developer Workbench. Its 'Disable Feed Tracking' setting had been set. This caused the flow *not* to create a Feed Item. Once I had deactivated the setting, updates via Developer Workbench and thus the flow created Feed Items.

This also shows that flows inherit the 'Disable Feed Tracking' setting.